# Expected ',' separator in completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying the following completion block in Swift. But, in the Swift converted code I get the error

> Expected ',' separator

I couldn't solve it for long time. Could someone advise me to solve this error please?

Obj-c:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
   [CoinbaseOAuth finishOAuthAuthenticationForUrl:url
                                         clientId:kCoinbaseDemoClientID
                                     clientSecret:kCoinbaseDemoClientSecret
                                       completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
   }];
   return YES;    
}
```

Swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    CoinbaseOAuth.finishOAuthAuthenticationForUrl(url : NSURL!, kCoinbaseDemoClientID: String!, kCoinbaseDemoClientSecret: String!) {(AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void in            
        println("Test message")
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this as follows:

```
CoinbaseOAuth.finishOAuthAuthenticationForUrl(url, clientId: kCoinbaseDemoClientID, clientSecret: kCoinbaseDemoClientSecret, completion: { (result, error) -> Void in
    println("Test message")
})
```

There is a bug in Xcode when you generate code for `completion` it erases parameter name and you get that error

Comment: Ok..just wanted to understand why did you vote down the question to -2

Comment: It is not mine downvote) And even if I downvote, I cannot do it more than once, just other community members think that you didn't elaborate enough in your question. Right now I upvoted your question, because it is hard a bit to notice that bug at Xcode, I faced this issue too but I was able to resolve it myself :) To make you believe me that I didn't downvote it, check your reputation: you will get +5 instead of +2 in case if I actually downvoted it)

Comment: Thank you..My worry was, this issue might occur to lot of people and answer is incredible to find, if someone down vote this unnecessarily, it won't reach all of them.